# MediaPlayer.isPlaying() does not return as True

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem.
I am using the mediaPlayer.isPlaying () command, but never that returns true.
When the audio is playing it still allows another audio to play along with the first one.
I have already used the following commands:

1 -

```
If (mediaPlayer.isPlaying () == true)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.stop ();
                    MediaPlayer.release ();

                } Else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying () == false)
                {
                    PlaySom ();
                }
```

---

2 -

```
If (! (MediaPlayer.isPlaying ()))
                {
                    PlaySom ();
                }
```

But without result, several audios are played at the same time, I would like you to play only one.

Does anyone know of any solution to the problem or some alternative to the mediaPlayer.isPlaying () command?

Thank you so much!!!

My Code:

```
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

// EVENTO DE CLIQUE

```
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, caminhoAudio[position]);

            if (!(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()))
            {
                tocarSom();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Aguarde o término do áudio para executar o outro.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        });
```

// INICIAR O SOM

```
public void tocarSom() {

        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        // LIBERAR MEMÓRIA
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();

            };
        });

    }
```

Comment: Just a note, you could replace your `else if` with a simple `else` ,  and `if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying () == true)` with `if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())`.

Comment: Yes it's true.
No need for if else.

But it still does not work, I do not know why.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you show how you are acquiring the mediaPlayer object?  Is it possible that you are creating multiple instances of it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I edited the question and put the code on top.

Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question due to if someone can get help from my answer...

You need to create top level (just below the class declaration) media Player like that

```
    private val player =
       MediaPlayer().apply {
       setOnPreparedListener { start() }
       setOnCompletionListener { reset() }
   }
```

After this create player sound method to play audio from storage

```
    private fun playBeats(context: Context, id: Uri)  {
         player.run {
             reset()
             setDataSource(context,id)
             prepareAsync()
         }
     }
```

If you love my answer please find my YouTube channel and subscribe to help me..

YouTube channel name : `codebage`